# Backtracking algorithm times out for difficult Sudoku puzzles

Tags: c#, algorithm, sudoku

This is my code for the back tracking logic.

```
private void backtrackLogic()
    {
       if (m == 0 && n != 0)
        {
            n--;
            m = 8;
            if(sudokuArray[n, m] == 0)
            {
                counter = copyArray[n, m];
                copyArray[n, m] = 0;
                if(counter == 9)
                {
                    backtrackLogic();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                backtrackLogic();
            }
        }
        else if (m != 0)
        {
            m--;
            if (sudokuArray[n, m] == 0)
            {
                counter = copyArray[n, m];
                copyArray[n, m] = 0;
                if (counter == 9)
                {
                    backtrackLogic();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                backtrackLogic();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Environment.Exit(0);
        }
    }
```

This is my code for the rest of the algorithm.

```
private void SolveButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++)
            {
                copyArray[i, j] = sudokuArray[i, j];
                Console.Write(sudokuArray[i, j]);
            }
        }

        counter = 1;
        bool noOptions = false;
        for (n = 0; n < 9; n++)
        {
            for (m = 0; m < 9; m++)
            {
                for (counter = 1; counter < 10; counter++)
                {
                    if (sudokuArray[n, m] == 0)
                    {
                        if (checkRow(n, m, counter) && checkColumn(n, m, counter) && checkBox(n, m, counter))
                        {
                            copyArray[n, m] = counter;
                            printTextBox(n, m, counter);
                            Console.Write(counter);
                            break;
                        }
                        else if (counter == 9)
                        {
                            noOptions = true;
                        }
                    }
                    if (noOptions)
                    {
                        backtrackLogic();
                        noOptions = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        for (int n = 0; n < 9; n++)
        {
            for (int m = 0; m < 9; m++)
            {
                Console.Write(copyArray[n, m]);
            }
        }
    }
```

When running this code on difficult Sudoku problems, the program times out because of how long it takes to execute. Any help in the execution of the algorithm would be very helpful!

Comment: What is a **difficult Sudoku problems**?

Comment: I found examples of premade puzzles online. The algorithm solves puzzles labeled easy, but not difficult. I think a general rule of thumb is that easier puzzles have more numbers filled in as well. @Shaharyar

Comment: Add the one on which it stuck. And what do you mean by **time out**, program becomes unresponsive?

Comment: 400000805
030000000
000700000
020000060
000080400
000010000
000603070
500200000
104000000
And yeah, the program becomes unresponsive after about a minute of running. @Shaharyar

Comment: @TheSweds Your example has too many unfilled cells and that's why your simple backtracking algorithm does not work well. You need some other techniques like forward checking and minimum remaining value heuristic. You can find more information on Peter Norvig's [website](http://norvig.com/sudoku.html).

Comment: In general you need a way to tell if your algorithm is making progress. If you give it a puzzle and it gets to point where it doesn't make progress then you will get a hang or time out.